# storybook doesn't find components based on chakra-ui

Tags: reactjs, configuration, storybook, chakra-ui

i was trying storybook and chakra ui.
Down below is how I structured my folders,

[image]

```
module.exports = {
  "stories": [
    "../src/**/*.stories.mdx",
    "../src/**/*.stories.@(js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
  ],
  "addons": [
    "@storybook/addon-links",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app"
  ]
}
```

and this is my storybook config.
unluckly i receive an error, it seems like storybook doesn't find my components. [image]

can someone help me to understand what's wrong ?
Why storybook doesn't find my components ?

-----------Update------------

this is the story that I tried to added

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Menu,
  MenuButton,
} from '@chakra-ui/core';

export function MenuComp() {
  return (
    <Menu>
      <MenuButton>Games</MenuButton>
    </Menu>
  );
}

MenuComp.storyName = 'test';
```

Comment: Have you wriiten any stories inside `Menu.stories.tsx` ?

Answer (score 2):

I started with an easier component and followed strictly the [tutorial](https://www.learnstorybook.com/intro-to-storybook/react/en/simple-component/)

i will wrote here a little guide that, I hope, will simplify the reader life.

1.I wrote a simple component in path "src/components/CustomButton"

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import { Button } from '@chakra-ui/core';

interface ButtonProps {
    size: string | any;
    variantColor: string;
}

const CustomButton: FC<ButtonProps> = ({ size, variantColor }) => (
  <Button variantColor={variantColor} size={size}>
    Button
  </Button>
);

export default CustomButton;
```

2.I added the relative story component in "src/stories/CustomButton.stories.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import CustomButton from 'components/CustomButton/index';

export default {
  component: CustomButton,
  title: 'CustomButton',
};

const Template = (args:any) => <CustomButton {...args} />;

export const Default: any = Template.bind({});
Default.args = {
  size: 'md',
  variantColor: 'green',
};
```

3.At this point it's really important configure your file preview.js that you will find the folder ".storybook", thanks to this commit [chakraUiCommit](https://github.com/with-heart/chakra-ui-storybook-issue/commit/ec4e457cdaab46f511f59344c630db5fc24f56f2) i figured out how to include the theme provider in every storybook component

```
import React from 'react'
import {addDecorator} from '@storybook/react'
import {ThemeProvider, CSSReset} from '@chakra-ui/core'

addDecorator((storyFn) => (
  <ThemeProvider>
    <CSSReset />
    {storyFn()}
  </ThemeProvider>
))
```

4. well, at this point i solved my problem, and this is my final result[image]